# C++ function to find a pattern in a list of floats?

Tags: c++

I have a list of 18 floats. Contained in this list of floats is a single pattern that occurs twice. I would like to be able to pick out this pattern without providing this specific pattern to the program.

I have tried to plan this several times both on a whiteboard and in Visual Studio. I get stuck trying to iterate forward/backward to find a continued pattern once I find the first float of each pattern. I also looked online for any examples but I could not find any that found any existing patterns in the list without being given a specific pattern.

Thanks and I appreciate all input/help!

Where I get stuck:

```
std::vector<float> RandomFloats =
{
    8.74,
    7.76,
    9.45,
    7.41, // Pattern Begin
    8.91,
    9.55,
    7.01,
    9.63, // Pattern End
    10.0,
    8.67,
    7.78,
    7.41, // Pattern Begin
    8.91,
    9.55,
    7.01,
    9.63, // Pattern End
    7.58,
    9.65,
    8.18
};
const static int FloatCount = RandomFloats.size();
    for (int i = 0; i < FloatCount; i++)
    {
        float fParent = RandomFloats.at(i);
        for (int j = 0; j < FloatCount; j++)
        {
            float fChild = RandomFloats.at(j);
            if (fChild != fParent)
                continue;
            // Check for continued pattern here.
        }
    }
```

Comment: Once you've found starting points, what's your problem to traverse the array?

Comment: Can the patterns overlap eachother?  _e.g._ `A B C A B C A` contains the pattern `A B C A` twice (with overlap)

Comment: I strongly recommend adding your attempt and research to the question. It helps a lot when answerers can see what you've already tried and rejected. Maybe you have a small mistake that's easily corrected. Maybe it won't be so easy, but at least the answerer won't have to go all the way back to the Book of Genesis to find a good place to start their answer. Also don't discount the social benefits of showing your work.

Comment: does 7.4100001 count as pattern start as well?

Comment: No, the patterns cannot overlap eachother. The pattern's floats are also limited to two decimals. I know I should have put more effort into an attempt. I got stuck doing research and now I am completely confused on how I would go about continuing to loop without ending up with like 20 for loops.

Comment: If they are limited to 2 decimals, ignore the fact they are "floats". If they are limited to 2 decimal points, and no E+/E- notation, then they are fixed point floats. Multiply them by 100 and run it as integers (or just parse them properly ignoring the dot). Treating it all as x100-scaled integers may save you some pesky floating point specifics like NaNs or inexact representations, and so on. But it's not vital. Just an observation and small simplification.

Comment: In your example, every other value that's not part of the pattern appears to be unique.  So, one way to do this is to simply run through the vector and put each value in a `std::set`.  Is it possible for there to be other patterns?  Does that include patterns that occur more than once?  Can a pattern have repeated values?  The specification of the problem is quite lacking, so recommending an actual solution is a challenge.

Comment: I like the idea of translating the floats into integers by multiplying by 100. I think I will check that path out! Thanks!

There can be multiple patterns. Patterns can occur multiple times. Patterns can have repeating values. Sorry for the lacking description, I honestly wasn't even sure what I was looking for. This is supposed to be used to identify patterns in pseudorandom generation of floats.

Comment: Consider each float a "character". Then apply any of well-known [pattern search algorithms](https://www.google.com/search?q=pattern+search+algorithm)

Comment: If we consider `float`s that do not match any other,as 'x', problem comes down to finding that pattern in  "xxxABCDExxxABCDExxx".

Comment: "I have a list of 18 floats." I count 19.

Comment: What about something like https://onlinegdb.com/ByEiHSkKw  or this https://onlinegdb.com/r1jbPHJFP (I like the second one better but it might be more cryptic)

Comment: If you want something that is the minimal change needed to get your code to work (so no histogram) try this: https://onlinegdb.com/Sy2_6SkFD

Comment: If you want to look into machine learning, what you got there is called a 'time series' and there are machine learning algorithms, which can identify patterns in that.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're on the right track with your current approach.  It's not particularly efficient, but it'll get the job done.

One problem is that the `j` loop starts at index 0.  This is unnecessary, and is going to cause you extra confusion.  Think about the *meaning* ("semantics") of that code.  The goal is to find the *next* occurrance of the value at position `i`.  Right now, you're searching the entire vector for it, which will actually find the value you're currently on, or even one that occurs earlier.  You don't want that!

So, start the loop at position `i + 1`, not at 0:

```
for (int i = 0; i < FloatCount; i++) {
    for (int j = i + 1; j < FloatCount; j++) {
        //   ^^^^^^^^^
    }
}
```

Then, you just need to write one more loop at your *"Check for continued pattern here"* part of the code.  Think about what that needs to do.  It's looking for a sequence of matching values such that the sequences don't overlap.

Think about what you know at that point.  You've found that index `i` and index `j` mark the potential start of a sequence, because the values in the vector are equal.  Now you need to check each value that follows until they either don't match, or you reach the end of the vector.

Putting those words into code:

```
int ii = i + 1;
int jj = j + 1;
while (jj < FloatCount &&    //<-- don't run off end of array
       ii < j &&             //<-- don't allow sequences to overlap
       RandomFloats[ii] == RandomFloats[jj])
{
    ++ii;
    ++jj;
}
```

After that, you know that both `ii` and `jj` indices are one-past-the-end of the sequence.  So the calculation of its length is simple:

```
int sequenceLength = ii - i;
```

The last bit is an exercise for you:

If a sequence might contain two identical values, or more generally if any value can appear more than once anywhere at all, then you also need to check whether the sequence you've found is better than any sequence you've found before.

To do that, you'll want some variables that remember the best sequence length so far, and where the two starting points of that sequence are.  Then, you can easily check this whenever you find a repeated sequence, and update it if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not wrong, what you are looking for is an adaptation of the [longest repeated substring problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_repeated_substring_problem).

In the original problem, given a string, you want to find the longest repeated subtring, this can be done in `O(n)` operations using a ***suffix tree***. Your question is exactly the same, but with numbers (each number is a letter), thus, the suffix tree should be altered so it stores numbers and not characters.

Going for the same approach can work in here as well, [you can check it here](https://daniel-hug.github.io/longest-repeated-substring/). (I have checked with your input, and it works perfectly, even though it is looking for recurring letters and not numbers, thus, less efficient).

Generally speaking, sometimes you want to find a problem that is similar, but has a solution, like here, it is very common to take a solution from one field, and import it to another.